# Difference between "./ [filename]" vs. "node [filename]"

Tags: node.js

could someone help me understand the difference between running a node script from terminal using `./ [Filename]` versus running it with `node [filename]` ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: ./[Filename] executes an executable file in the current directory, whereas node [Filename] executes the file with node. The main difference where is when using node you don't necessarily run executables, but rather javascript files that the system may not be able to execute specifically.

Comment: Sounds like a subtle difference but I am sure has large implications when you fully understand what is going on. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as running bash script using `./[Filename]` or `bash [Filename]`.

To use `./[Filename]` syntax your node script should:

- be runable (`chmod +x [Filename]`)
- contain proper header (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/node` or `#!/usr/bin/env node`)

There is no requirements for running your script with `node [Filename]`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any advantage to me making the script executable and running via ./ versus just running with "node" if only the owner needs to run it?

Comment: You could add it into `/usr/local/bin` and execute it globally without having to do `./` or `node` saving a small amount of typing and effort? I cant see any specific advantage if its just the owner using it. Are you likely to be using any flags with the `node` command? If so, using `./` may create some issues.

Comment: @Reno It's very handy when you need to run the same script multiple times using console, or if you want to place it to your path and run from anywhere.